# purchase_landed_costs module Error openerp 7

Tags: python, xml, odoo

```
File "/home/bellvantage/Documents/openerp-7.0/openerp-7.0/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 2177, in apply_inheritance_specs
    raise_view_error("Element '%s' not found in parent view '%%(parent_xml_id)s'" % tag, inherit_id)
  File "/home/bellvantage/Documents/openerp-7.0/openerp-7.0/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 2070, in raise_view_error
    %  (child_view.xml_id, self._name, error_msg))
AttributeError: View definition error for inherited view 'purchase_landed_costs.c2c_product_landed_cost_view' on model 'product.product': Element '<field name="active">' not found in parent view 'product.product_normal_form_view'
```

when i go to create products in products form this error appeared.
what is the issue with thia

here is my fresh DB & no any issues with other modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thin bug in the purchase_landed_cost module, you try to install 6.1 version module in 7 version. Now field active now no more exits in product_normal_form_view.

Comment: Hi again :-)
r they issue a module which support to version 7

Comment: sorry friend this module is camp2camp, currently they put version 7 code no where, but if you want to run this module got to purchase_view.xml file of this module line no 44 "c2c_product_landed_cost_view" and  change from  **<field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.product_normal_form_view"/>** to **<field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.view_normal_procurement_locations_form"/>** then it module install and work dear enjoy!!! :)

Comment: Are they affect to cost value of cost.i purchase sample product and tick "Calculate Landed Costs" also.but when P/O received and posted GL not shows them. is there anything to do more that that.?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27626/discussion-between-priyan-rockz-and-user1576199)